# Setting up Cage kiosk - rotating the touch input to match screen rotation

Tags: linux, debian, wayland, touch-screen

I'm VERY new to Linux, I have a "kiosk PC" with integrated touch screen that's deployed in portrait mode but the hardware thinks it's landscape. I'm currently running Debian 12 on the machine, I've set up the Cage kiosk compositor (https://github.com/cage-kiosk/cage) and managed to rotate it to match the intended device orientation. However, the touch input still thinks that the screen is in landscape mode, so the locations of the touch events don't correspond with the placement of buttons on the screen.

The project's Wiki has an entry dealing with this issue:

https://github.com/cage-kiosk/cage/wiki/Troubleshooting#touch-input-isnt-transformed-correctly-to-my-transformed-touch-output

I would like to ask for help decoding this entry.

It instructs to add a file to /etc/udev/rules.d/ (so far so good), and then it gives an example:

```
KERNEL=="event[0-9]", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="FT5406 memory based driver", ENV{WL_OUTPUT}="DSI-1"
```

Then it says

```
"This requires you to know the path in /dev of your input device and the name of your output device. The latter is printed by Cage (look for a log line "Scanning DRM connectors"),
```

What do they mean by this? Where does Cage print this value? I've gone through the logs in journalctl, I didn't find anything resembling that log line. (maybe I'm looking in the wrong place? Again, I'm very new to this). Is there an alternate way of finding the touchscreen name?

Then it goes on to say

```
the former requires a bit of experimenting with devices listed under

/dev/input/
```

Does this mean I'll have to keep editing the file and switching out the KERNEL="event[0-9]" parameter until I find one that works? My /dev/input/ directory has files event0 through event22, js0, mice, mouse0, mouse1, mouse2. That's 28 files :/

My by-id folder has the following entries:
[image]

Many of these I can tell are something else, like a physical keyboard and some scanners, but still, there are three entries related to touch input device. How do I pick the right one and match it to event* from /dev/input ?